# The use of inline functions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function, inline

I do not understand the point of 'inline functions'.
I know they are faster (such as macros) than ordinary functions, but why isn't every function an 'inline-function'?

Answer (score 1):

Functions that are called from more than one place in code *could* be inlined, but the expense of that (ever so slight) performance boost is code size. Generally it's considered better to add the few instructions to make a subroutine call than it is to consume additional space inlining a function.

Functions that are called from exactly one place may be inlined without extra overhead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code size - if a function is called from multiple locations duplicating the code everywhere can quickly cause significant growth in overall code size.
2. Code size - Infinite! It is simply impossible to inline code which is recursive, directly or indirectly.